# No method matching pcacov

Tags: machine-learning, julia, pca

I am trying to apply PCA to reduce dimensionality and noise using Julia language but am getting an error message. Could you please help me to solve this issue.

Are there other alternatives in julia to the perform the same task?

Here's the error message:

```
julia> X = (train_input)' |> Array;

julia> typeof(X)
Matrix{Real} (alias for Array{Real, 2})

julia> using MultivariateStats, MLJMultivariateStatsInterface

julia> M = fit(PCA, X; maxoutdim = 3)
MethodError: no method matching pcacov(::Matrix{Float64}, ::Vector{Real}; maxoutdim=3, pratio=0.99)
Closest candidates are: 
  pcacov(::AbstractMatrix{T}, ::AbstractVector{T}; maxoutdim, pratio) where T<: Real at C:\Users\USER\.julia\packages\MultivariateStats\rCiqT\src\pca.jl:209
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do **not** post screenshots of code or error messages, see how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 4):

I can't reproduce your error. But this is how I get the job done via the `MultivariateStats v0.10.0` package in the case of fitting a PCA model:

```
julia> using MultivariateStats

julia> X = rand(5, 100);
       fit(PCA, X, maxoutdim=3)
PCA(indim = 5, outdim = 3, principalratio = 0.6599153346885055)

Pattern matrix (unstandardized loadings):
────────────────────────────────────
         PC1         PC2         PC3
────────────────────────────────────
1  0.201331   -0.0213382   0.0748083
2  0.0394825   0.137933    0.213251
3  0.14079     0.213082   -0.119594
4  0.154639   -0.0585538  -0.0975059
5  0.15221    -0.145161    0.0554158
────────────────────────────────────

Importance of components:
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                PC1        PC2        PC3
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
SS Loadings (Eigenvalues)  0.108996  0.0893847  0.0779532
Variance explained         0.260295  0.21346    0.186161
Cumulative variance        0.260295  0.473755   0.659915
Proportion explained       0.394436  0.323466   0.282098
Cumulative proportion      0.394436  0.717902   1.0
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

julia> typeof(X)
Matrix{Float64} (alias for Array{Float64, 2})

julia> eltype(X)
Float64
```

As you can see, I used a `Matrix` with `Float64` element types as the input. This is the difference between my input in comparison with yours, I guess. So this might be the problem in your case.
Keep in mind that rows represent the features and the columns represent the data samples!
Finally, since you asked for other alternatives, I introduce you to the [`WeightedPCA` package](https://dahong67.github.io/WeightedPCA.jl/stable/#Docstrings). *This package provides weighted principal component analysis (PCA) for data with samples of heterogeneous quality (heteroscedastic noise)*. Here is a quick example:

```
julia> using WeightedPCA

julia> X = rand(5, 100);
       pc1, pc2, pc3 = wpca.(Ref(collect(eachrow(X))), [1, 2, 3], Ref(UniformWeights()));
```

In the above, I fitted an equally weighted PCA on the `X` data and I requested values on 1, 2, and 3 principal components. Using this package, you can even apply specific weights or optimal weights. This package can be installed by `pkg> add https://github.com/dahong67/WeightedPCA.jl`.
Furtherore, as [Antonello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74494901/no-method-matching-pcacov/74495080#comment131504340_74495080) said, one can utilize [`BetaML`](https://sylvaticus.github.io/BetaML.jl/stable/index.html) package to perform PCA. This package *provides machine learning algorithms written in the Julia programming language*. Let's [use it to perform PCA](https://sylvaticus.github.io/BetaML.jl/dev/Utils.html#BetaML.Utils.PCA):

```
julia> using BetaML

julia> X = rand(100, 5);

julia> mod = PCA(max_unexplained_var=0.3)
A PCA BetaMLModel (unfitted)

julia> reproj_X = fit!(mod,X)
100×4 Matrix{Float64}:
  0.204151    -0.482558  -0.161929   0.222503
  0.69425     -0.371519  -0.628404   0.462256
  0.198191    -0.601537  -0.638573   0.463886
  ⋮                                 
 -0.00176858   0.557353  -0.4237     0.310565
  0.533239     0.133691  -0.236009  -0.0793025
  0.333652    -0.388115  -0.28662    0.481249

julia> info(mod)
Dict{String, Any} with 5 entries:
  "explained_var_by_dim" => [0.277255, 0.484764, 0.669897, 0.846831, 1.0]
  "fitted_records"       => 100
  "prop_explained_var"   => 0.846831
  "retained_dims"        => 4
  "xndims"               => 5
```

In the above, the `max_unexplained_var` specifies *the actual proportion of variance not explained in the reprojected dimensions* or in other words, the maximum unexplained variance that I'm ready to accept.

Comment: [Another package that does PCA](https://sylvaticus.github.io/BetaML.jl/stable/Utils.html#BetaML.Utils.PCA) (records in rows, dims in cols), more ML than stat.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is telling you that somewhere in the PCA fit an internal function is called which requires an `AbstractMatrix{T}` and an `AbstractVector{T}` as an input, which means that the element type of both arguments `T` needs to be the same. In your case a `Matrix{Float64}` and a `Vector{Real}` is being passed. I assume that the `Vector{Real}` comes from your `X` input which as your first cell shows is a `Matrix{Real}`.

This generally indicates an issue in the construction of `X`, which shouldn't have an abstract element type like `Real`. Try `float.(X)` as an input to coerce all elements to `Float64`.

Comment: Sorry but this my first question, I will make sure to do that next time & thank you! it's working now, I just converted the data type to float, but now it keeps consider that outdim = 1 (showing the results of pc1 only) even though I am specifying that maxoutdim=3 same as in the picture... sorry again but I dont know how to post code block in the comment

Comment: That's a different question, which warrants being asked separately (this time with a proper copy-pastable MWE)